# Analyzing the log backups to understand the pattern

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, transaction-log

I am not sure if my understanding is correct on this behavior of log backups.

We believe the increase in traffic, as log backups have increased after migration event to cluster from stanadlone SQL 2012.

Per the monthly analysis of log backups running every 10 mins, in a day for an avg i calculated the log backup size to be 400-450 GB. Now post migration, its been week and i can see that log backup size has increased to an avg of 650-700 GB in a day.

App says there is no increase in volume, so i am wandering why there is sudden increase in log backups.

Log file is same before and after =200 GB and VLF's 300.

Database is 10 TB on SQL server 2012 and many a tables are partitioned.

Let me know if there is further details needed to understand this behavior? Or is there another way to analyse this? Please suggest

Comment: You can't correlate log backup size with traffic as the log is what changes have occurred. Since a migration was done, there is a possibility that different maintenance items are happening - check to see the times when the log backups are larger than previous, if there is a spike for example and correlate times. Then you can dig into the log, but the log is not very readable even using undocumented functions. Good luck.

Comment: Flag as dupe which contains answers with great detail about log t-log growth.  Ultimately as mentioned in the comments the OP needs to expand what they are looking at